# WebException: The underlying connection was closed

Tags: c#, asp.net, timeout, http-status-code-404, system.net.webexception

I am currently calling a webservice from an ASP.net page.  I am trying to call a REST based web service to request a certain action and a 404 is returned (which represents a specific error for my application).  I try to catch the error but as a 404 is returned my application instead continues to hang and I end up catching the following error.

[System.Net.WebException] = {"The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive."}

Why would I catch a different error over 2 seconds after the web service responds with a 404?

```
try
{
    newPassword = Customer.ResetPassword(_transaction.Centre.Id, newPassword);
}
catch(WebException ex)
{
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;

    if ((response != null) && (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound))
    {
        //then the email address doesnt exist
        ErrorPage(104);
    }
    else
    {
         ErrorPage();
    }
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
    ErrorPage();
 }
```

and that calls this:

```
Request currentRequest = new Request(uri,
            Communication.Request.HttpRequestType.POST,[hidden][hidden]);

Response response = currentRequest.Send(Serializer.Serialize<ResetPassword (resetPassword));

return Serializer.Deserialize<ResetPassword>(response.BodyData);
```

Please ignore the [hidden] tags.  Ive had to hide that from public view.  However, I hope that helps.

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Please show the code. The problem is more likely to be in your code than in .NET.

Comment: So let me get this straight. `Customer.ResetPassword` calls the 2nd block of code. Which calls a URI to perform a password reset. Is all of this client code or the web-service that's offending? What initializes this code? Where's the entry point?

Comment: Thats right. The entry point is attached to a Click event.  So on "reset password" button click it calls the second block of code.  It is the client code that is offending.  Its doesnt seem to recieve the 404 even though the web service responds with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've provided little information about your system:

You are **probably** terminating your web service call early with something like

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.End()
```

The webservice code (in .NET) is probably trying to complete the request but you've closed the connection early. This happens with `Response.Redirect()` too but you never see it on the web-side because you've already completed the output to the user. It's not related to your 404. The web-service code throws the `WebException` but there's nothing to handle / format the output.

---

**Update**

Based on your feedback I can only deduce that your problem is probably either:

1. In the Data sent to the webservice
2. In how the webservice handles the data

You should download [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and sniff the http request to your webservice to verify what's actually going across the wire. If everything checks out then there's only 2 things I can think of:

1. Something about your `Request`/`Response` is not right. You could use a `WebClient` Instead and call either `UploadData(...)` or `UploadString(...)` to transmit your data to the webservice.
2. Something is wrong in the webservice that's causing it to close the connection before terminating the response the way your client expects it.

**WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.** Should only happen when the client expects to recieve data (like a body after a header) but the server terminates the response early.

Comment: A little more detail if it can help.

I request a forgotten password and post the email address to change the password.  If no email exists in our database it returns a 404.  My Client ASP.net app is supposed to catch the 404 but instead catches a timeout after around 2 seconds of the 404 being returned to the client.

I hope that helps, by the way, thanks for your current response!

Comment: @Base33: Likewise, you haven't given me enough to go on here. My answer basically explains where that exception typically comes from. Without code examples, I can't really narrow it down.

Comment: Still need more specifics. Have you debugged inside this function? If so, can you narrow down which lines are causing the holdup? Are you using WCF? or plain-old-webservices? What type are you returning? **Are** you returning, or using an escape method like `Resonse.End()`. How are you returning the email to the client? Please edit your question with more information & preferably snip-its from the offending code so we can help.

Comment: Nope not using Response.End().  I have debugged and it seems to hang in the currentRequest.Send.  It should recieve the response and cause the client to catch the 404.

Comment: Thanks!  Thats pretty much what was needed.